# Style Icon on Input Focus

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to have my search icon next to my input form change colors when I focus but I cant seem to find the right selector. If I manually add a focus event on the form itself this will work but not on the input. What's going on here?

**HTML**

```
<form action="/search" class="form-inline" method="get">
  <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></div>
  <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" data-turboform="" name="search" placeholder="Search for your products!" value="" type="text">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      Translate my search
      <span class="bold">?</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="text"]:focus .glyphicon-search{
  color: $bp-orange
}
```

Comment: Glyphicons are small images, you cannot change their color in an easy way.  Either you will use "font awesom" or you add filters to your glyphicon.

Comment: @TobiasK. There fonts not images same with font-awesome. You are able to change `color` via css

Comment: With CSS you can't select the previous element. You have to use JS.

Comment: @NooBskie is right. With your selection you are seraching the child of input[type="text"]:focus

Comment: @NooBskie Is the search icon supposed to do anything here or is it just used as a visual? How do users submit the search?

Comment: Currently just visual, ill switch it to a input later most likely just wanted to get the styling correct first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `+` selector which apply css on next sibling but for that you need to put `input` first and then the glyphicon in html.

```
input[type="text"]:focus + .glyphicon-search{
  color: $bp-orange
}

<form action="/search" class="form-inline" method="get">
  <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" data-turboform="" name="search" placeholder="Search for your products!" value="" type="text">
  <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      Translate my search
      <span class="bold">?</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This worked i just ended up adding `float:left` to the glyphicon to keep the same styling. Thanks